# Working with lists in PHP

Tags: php, python, arrays

I need to rewrite some Python code into PHP (don't hate me, a customer asked me to do so)

In Python you can do something like this:

```
// Python
numbers = [34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7]
positive = [int(n) for n in numbers if n > 0]
negative = [int(n) for n in numbers if n < 0]
```

But if you try something like this in PHP it doesn't work:

```
// PHP
$numbers = array(34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7);
$positive = array(intval($n) for $n in $numbers if $n > 0);
$negative = array(intval($n) for $n in $numbers if $n > 0);
```

Instead of doing something like:

```
<?php
$numbers = array(34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7);

$positive = array();
$negative = array();

foreach($numbers as $n) {

    if($n > 0):
        $positive[] = intval($n);
    else:
        $negative[] = intval($n);
    endif;
}
?>
```

Is there a way to write this with less code like you can do in Python?

Comment: Downvoting without explaining why it's downvoted isn't very constructive..

Comment: -1 comes across as a Python is better than PHP because I can write things in fewer characters in python unless somebody can prove otherwise

Comment: @MarkBaker The only reason I use PHP is that our customer pays for it. We prefer Python ourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) and anonymous functions (the latter only if you have PHP 5.3 or higher), but the way that you showed with more code is more efficient and looks neater to me.

```
$positive = array_filter($numbers, function($x) { return $x > 0; });
$negative = array_filter($numbers, function($x) { return $x < 0; });
```

And [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to apply `intval`:

```
$positive = array_map('intval', array_filter($numbers, function($x) { return $x > 0; }));
$negative = array_map('intval', array_filter($numbers, function($x) { return $x < 0; }));
```

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin: Read the parentheses more carefully next time :)

Comment: People always mentioning that something only works on 5.3 is unnecessary. If someone is using an older version of PHP he is doomed anyways.

Comment: @NikiC Right on. I'm using PHP 5.4 and loving every feature of it :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter)

```
$positive = array_filter($numbers,function($a) {return $a > 0;});
$negative = array_filter($numbers,function($a) {return $a < 0;});
```

Comment: PHP 5.3 is not a problem Mathieu

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a bit more verbose in the array / map handling, it's one of Python's strengths. There are some functions that can help with dealing with arrays, like for instance:

```
$positive = array_filter($numbers,function($n){return $n > 0;});
$positive = array_map('intval',$positive);
$negative = array_filter($numbers,function($n){return $n < 0;});
$negative = array_map('intval',$positive);
```

Comment: PHP 5.3 was released 30 June 2009, people stuck at lower versions, especially for _new_ projects like this, need to seriously reconsider either their server maintenance or their hoster.

Comment: Yea.. PHP 5.3 is installed on our server

Answer (score -2):

No... As far as I am aware, foreach loop is the only way to go.

And this is not that much more of code.

But if you want to make it a little shorter, you can get rid of explicit array declarations just before the foreach loop.

Comment: Getting rid of the explicit array declarations would cause warnings.